# Error converting a numeric month into textural representation

Tags: php

I am using the following code in php to convert the month in numeric to textural representation.

```
date('M',strtotime(8));
```

But for every digit I am getting 'Dec' as my month.

How should i make it work.

Thank you 
Zeeshan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But for every digit I am getting 'Dec' as my month.

That's no surprise: `strtotime(8)` will give you `0` - and that is January 1st, 1970, 0:00:00 UTC, in your local time zone (where it was still december at that point).

You could use

```
$month = 8;
date("M", strtotime("1970-$month-01"));
```

(the `1970` is totally irrelevant - it could be any year.)

Alternatively, maybe more beautifully, use `mktime()` as shown by nikic.

Answer (score 2):

`strtotime` expects a date string, not a single month. You may use [`mktime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) to create your month:

```
 date('M', mktime(0, 0, 0, $month));
```